# Unlock Bootloader on Samsung Galaxy S6 AT&T

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-6, bootloader-lock

I'm trying to root my phone, and I was told that because I own a Galaxy S6, I need to unlock my bootloader. My carrier is AT&T, which makes it apparently even more difficult. I've tried things such as fastboot, which will get stuck telling me `waiting for device input`. I'll look that up, and it turns out I need to install PdaNet if that happens. Of course, PdaNet is blocked by AT&T and there's no way to install it.

I've found at least a dozen articles and the like on the matter, and none of them have worked. If anyone's got some advice, or even just a flat-out "it can't be done", I'd greatly appreciate that. I'd also like to know if unlocking the bootloader is necessary, and if it isn't, I'd love to know what I've been doing wrong, and what my next steps should be or what guides are good and up-to-date. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: At this moment, "flat-out 'it can't be done'". Once again, a lesson not to buy phones from AT&T and Verizon again. P.S. normally Samsung devices have no `fastboot`.

Comment: @AndyYan is there some other way to proceed with the rooting process that doesn't involve unlocking the bootloader?

Comment: From what's in [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s6), nope. Modern phones pretty much deny rooting methods other than installing a recovery and a SU package.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @AndyYan Also, this link from XDA seems to suggest otherwise: https://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s6/development/root-att-samsung-g920a-s6-g925a-s7edge-t3564637

Comment: Probably feasible, as long as your current firmware version is lower.

Comment: @AndyYan What do you mean? Also, I'm running Nougat, is that a problem?

Comment: @AndyYan Also, if I were to flash an international firmware for the G920F, would I still be able to use the AT&T network?

Comment: Running Nougat means your bootloader is already updated to the same, thus it won't take an older "Eng boot", and you can't use the method above. Also, you **can't** flash something for another model - Samsung doesn't make it that easy for you. See why I said AT&T and Verizon suck? They lock down and you don't even have a way to escape.

Comment: @AndyYan Well, I downgraded my firmware to Marshmallow through Odin, but I'm really not sure how to continue with that tutorial. Flashing that Engboot file through Odin works, but doesn't change anything, and I don't know what they mean by that whole SuperSU thing at the bottom. This is my first time rooting, and I greatly appreciate your help so far.

Comment: @AndyYan I was also planning on using Magisk, so I don't know if that changes anything...